# How is bluetoothd daemonized?

Tags: bluez

I am looking at the source code of bluez-5.56, trying to understand how bluetoothd is daemonized.
I don't see any calls to daemon or fork.
Could you point me to the location where daemonizing happens? I am compiling the code on openwrt.

I collected all the relevant source files as they appear in Makefile.am and searched through them for 'daemon' or 'fork', but couldn't find any.